# what's the meaning of “Fpfit. ”

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of “Fpfit. ” in following pic
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific term that is limited to a specific subject.

Answer (score 1):

*Fpfit* means *Fractional-Polynomial Fit*. (Etymology: It's the term usually used in the statistical software package STATA.)

A fractional-polynomial fit is a statistical model (form of linear regression) that attempts to fit a predicting function onto some dataset.

Comment: Is that a sophisticated way of 'drawing a line of best fit', which is the way I would have learned it at school?